# Chartjs Line chart options display increase and decrease percentage between each datapoint

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm using chartjs to create charts and I'm using the Line Chart and editing it's options here. I have a few data points/values and I have to figure out how much the percentage between each is ( if it has increased or decreased ). The current codes is close to doing that but it doesn't work properly, it finds decrease and increase based on `currentValue`. My question is how can I make it that it checks based on each data value?

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKPZh.png)

Check the picture out, it is supposed to find the decrease/increase from the value before and not the first one.

```js
const options = {
  tooltips: {
    callbacks: {
      label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
        var dataset = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex];
        var firstValue = dataset.data.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, currentIndex, array) {
          return previousValue;
        });
        var secondValue = dataset.data.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, currentIndex, array) {
          return currentValue;
        });
        var currentValue = dataset.data[tooltipItem.index];
        var precentage = parseFloat((currentValue - firstValue) * 100 / firstValue).toFixed(1);         
        return currentValue + ' (' + precentage + "%)";
      },
      title: function(tooltipItem, data) {
        return data.labels[tooltipItem[0].index];
      }
    }
  },
}
```

Comment: so the maximum value in the graph would represent 100%?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you need something like this to match the previous record.

```
const options = {
  tooltips: {
    callbacks: {
      label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
        var dataset = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex];
        var currentValue = dataset.data[tooltipItem.index];
        var precentage, previousValue;
        if(tooltipItem.index - 1 >= 0) {
            previousValue = dataset.data[tooltipItem.index - 1];
            precentage = parseFloat((currentValue - previousValue) * 100 / previousValue).toFixed(1);
        } else {
            precentage = 0;
        }         
        return currentValue + ' (' + precentage + "%)";
      },
      title: function(tooltipItem, data) {
        return data.labels[tooltipItem[0].index];
      }
    }
  },
}
```